# Quantum measurement problem with eigenvectors (Dirac notation)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, measurement-problem, probability

Ok so I've got two state vectors related to two other state vectors.

$$|\alpha_1\rangle= (1/5)(3|\gamma_1\rangle+4|\gamma_2\rangle)$$

$$|\alpha_2\rangle= (1/5)(4|\gamma_1\rangle-3|\gamma_2\rangle)$$

There are two  measurable quantities, $a$ and $b$ associated with their operators: $A$ and $B$. Operator $A$ has two eigenvectors: $|\alpha_1\rangle$ and $|\alpha_2\rangle$, operator $B$ has two as well: $|\gamma_1\rangle$ and $|\gamma_2\rangle$. First we measure quantity $a$ and the system is in state $|\alpha_1\rangle$. Then we measure again and find the quantity $b$. If the third measurement is quantity $a$ what is the probability that the system is in state $|\alpha_1\rangle$? I need to express the answer as a fraction.

Breakdown of the measurements:

1.) Observable $a$ is measured and we discover that the state of the system is $|\alpha_1\rangle$.

2.) Observable $b$ is measured, unknown state: either $|\gamma_1\rangle$ or $|\gamma_2\rangle$

3.) Observable $a$ is measured, what is the probability we have state $|\alpha_1\rangle$

Comment: To be clear, when you say measuring quantity "a" and "b", do you mean make a measurement that corresponds to operator "A" and "B", or do you mean some specific value "a" or "b"?

Comment: The measurement "a" is a specific value measured by our equipment that is associated with the operator "A" that has two possible state vectors. Likewise, the measurement "b" is a specific value measured by our equipment associated with the operator "B" which has two possible state vectors.

Comment: Ok, I'm a little confused because if measuring "a" in the first measurement collapses you to $| \alpha_1 \rangle$, then measuring "a" in the third measurement should also collapse you to $| \alpha_1 \rangle$ with probability 1. That's kind of simple though, is that something your professor would do?

Comment: This is something my professor would do. Why wouldn't it be possible for the system to collapse into |$\alpha_2\rangle$?

Comment: I'll make this an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't quite clear to me precisely what is being asked so consider this to be simply a guess.

First I assume the measurements are made one after the other.  Immediately after the first measurement of the the observable A is made, the system is in the state $| \alpha_1\rangle$.

Then a measurement of the observable B is made and there is a $\frac{9}{25}$ probability that the system is in state $| \gamma_1\rangle$ and a $\frac{16}{25}$ probability that the system is in state $| \gamma_2\rangle$.

Immediately, another measurement of the observable A is made.  So, to find the answer, you must express $| \gamma_1\rangle$ and $| \gamma_2\rangle$ in terms of $| \alpha_1\rangle$ and $| \alpha_2\rangle$, compute the two conditional probabilities  and then sum.

Comment: See, this is the question I would expect, but my follow up comments it seems like the third measurement is actually already given. @That1guy: this is the correct procedure if that is not the case

Answer (score 0):

There's an ambiguity here, somewhat. I'm assuming that the states are intended to be non-degenerate. By that I mean, I'm assuming $| \alpha_1 \rangle$ and $| \alpha_2 \rangle$ correspond to two different states of the system with two different eigenvalues. Let's call their eigenvalues $a_1$ and $a_2$. What this means is that if you measure $A$ on $| \alpha_i \rangle$ you definitely get the result $a_i$.

Now, you can measure a mixed state, like $x | \alpha_1 \rangle + y | \alpha_2 \rangle$, and then you will get either $a_1$ or $a_2$. The probabilities for each is just the squared amplitude corresponding to each: $P(a_1) = |x|^2$, $P(a_2) = |y|^2$.

The key thing to note, though, is that after the measurement, the state collapses to the eigenvector corresponding to the measurement you made. If this were a spin-half system and you measured spin-up then, right after the measurement, you would know you had $| \uparrow \rangle$ for instance. Why this is is somewhat mysterious; it gets into interpretations of QM that attempt to solve the question of why measurement has this effect. That's tremendously interesting, but you don't need it solve the question.

The sequence of events for you is that we start in some state $| \psi \rangle$. Then we measure $A$, and we get a particular value $a$. We are told that after this measurement we are in state $| \alpha_1 \rangle$. That means that $a$ is the eigenvalue corresponding to $| \alpha_1 \rangle$. So we make another measurement on $B$, and we get an eigenvalue of that operator--$| \gamma_i \rangle$. We don't know which. But then we make another $A$ measurement and we get $a$ again. But we know that the $a$ eigenvalue corresponds to $| \alpha_1 \rangle$, so that must be our new state.

Complications would arise: (1) if $a_1 = a_2$, so measuring the value doesn't collapse you definitely into one or the other eigenstate or (2) if the problem asked us to predict the probability of getting $| \alpha_1 \rangle$ before the measurement. I don't think we could do (2) without more information, though, specifically the result of the second measurement.